# sql query to convert new line character to a html <br>

Tags: mysql, html, expressionengine

I have a mysql database of articles that were entered into a textarea with no formatting, they use only a newline character for line breaks

```
\n
```

I need to convert all of these into html br tags

```
<br />
```

can you help me write a query to do this that I can run in phpmyadmin that will do this?

the name of the table is

```
exp_channel_data
```

---

as a bonus question...

Is there a query I can run that will strip everything out of the middle of p and span tags

I want to get rid of this stuff

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt">
<span face="Times New Roman">
```

and end up with just this

```
<p>
<span>
```

Comment: Just in case you don't already know about this, please read up on SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. You really, really, don't want to have SQL in your database.
Also, in general, I'd strongly recommend doing this kind of formatting work outside the database.

Comment: ya I'm actually not including any SQL in the database (I think), this is just a one time conversion I need to run, appreciate the tip

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First question:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET text_column = REPLACE(text_column, '\r\n', '<br />')
```

If it doesn't replace anything, use `'\n'` instead of `'\r\n'`.

Second question:

You can't do it with a SQL query, you have to fetch this data into a PHP script, or anything else you like, and perform a regular expression replace (example for PHP):

```
$new_str = preg_replace('#<(p|span)[^>]+>#', '<$1>', $old_string);
```

Comment: For the second question use mariadb instead of mysql and exercise REGEXP_REPLACE()

Comment: I have used it this way in the php trim(preg_replace('/\r\n/', '&#10;', $text));

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET text=REPLACE(text,"\n","<br />")
```

This works for your first question.

Comment: That's not a valid SQL syntax

Comment: @Crack, yeah sorry about that. Way too hot and humid in Germany right now.

Comment: Heh, share your sun. 19°C and rainy in Poland ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ExpressionEngine, you can just change the format of each field to XHTML. It will add the `<br />` markup when displayed on the front-end. bet to keep your data clean and leave the formatting to the parser displaying it.

Comment: I'm actually switching from a textarea fieldtype with auto br formatting to NSM TinyMCE and want to preserve the breaks, if I don't do this the text all runs together, if I wasn't switching fieldtypes your solution would be a good one

Answer (score 0):

IF someone happens to look for a PHP-side solution, use the `nl2br` function... it worked for me. It converts those nasty line breaks to HTML `<br>` tags during runtime.

https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_nl2br.asp