# Expression Engine - Remove &nbsp; from field?

Tags: expressionengine, html-entities

Im using channel tags to display content for an RSS feed. The issue is that the content has been imported and contains `&nbsp;`, which makes the feed fail validation and screws up in some readers.

Is their a way to strip out the `&nbsp;`? I've 2 modules that can strip out markup but neither can remove the `&nbsp;`
http://supergeekery.com/geekblog/comments/expression_engine_2_plugin_supergeekery_tag_stripper_version_1.0
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/html-plugin

Could this be done with some custom PHP?
Thanks

Comment: How do the non-breaking spaces appear in the control panel and database? Are they written out encoded as you show, or are they non-printing unicode characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177007/sql-query-to-convert-new-line-character-to-a-html-br/7177350#7177350) on a similar question should help. Just run this query on the database to get rid of the non-breaking spaces altogether. (Use phpMyAdmin or similar.)

`UPDATE exp_channel_data SET text_column = REPLACE(field_id_XX, '&nbsp;', ' ')`

Replace `field_id_XX` with the actual name of your column(s).

Comment: The content is imported regularly so I cant just run the query once. Also the content is displayed elsewhere in the site so if i change it in the database I may cause problems elsewhere. Thanks